# Update registration via link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to update a record without using a form, just using `link_to` , it would be something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Publish", pedidos_path(pedido, pedido: {Status: 3}), method: :put,:remote => true %>
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Started PUT "/pedidos.21148?pedido%5BStatus%5D=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-04 11:23:19 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/pedidos.21148"):
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
```

This is my route:

```
resources :pedidos
```

Comment: Can you add your routes.rb file?

Comment: You need to add a PUT route. Use PATCH instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the correct update route, i.e `pedido_path` instead of `pedidos_path`:

```
<%= link_to "Publish", pedido_path(pedido, pedido: {Status: 3}), method: :put %>
```

And if you want to use this as an AJAX request then you can try this:

```
<%= link_to "Publish", pedido_path(pedido, pedido: {Status: 3}), method: :put, remote: true %>
```